# Rounding dates to the day in an SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am stuck with something.  I am trying to take a long column of dates of which are formated to show also hours and minutes and run a Group query to paste values at the date level without acknowledging the differences in hours and minutes..  Unfortunately I have no clue how to start.  The code i put together so far which returns each grouped date with the hour and minutes is as follows:

```
st_sql = "INSERT INTO [tblSearchEngine03] ([Date])" & _
    "SELECT [tblSearchEngine02].[Date]" & _
    "FROM [tblSearchEngine02]" & _
    "GROUP BY [tblSearchEngine02].[Date]" & _
    "ORDER BY [tblSearchEngine02].[Date]"

    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Im not sure the best way to truncate the date on table "tblSearchEngine02"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to format the date/time as a date string. If you use `YYYY/MM/DD` it will sort properly. Otherwise you can convert the date/time to an int to trim off the time and then convert back to a date/time type.

Here is an example of formatting as string:

```
Format([tblSearchEngine02].[Date], "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Here is an exmple of converting to get to a date (the end result will be a date/time data type so it might render as `03/16/2014 00:00` depending on your locale info)

```
CDate(CInt([tblSearchEngine02].[Date]))
```

Comment: Thanks Attila.   I am a bit new to programming so please excuse my ignorance..  You are talking about writing something in VBA correct ???

Comment: You should be able to do this in your query. I can update my answer with the SQL to do this.

Comment: Attila, would you be so kind to show me a sample of what you mean by formating the date/time as a string??

Comment: try this: **Format([tblSearchEngine02].[Date], "yyyy/mm/dd")**

Comment: fantastic.  does this get inserted into the SQL routine i used above or is it separate in the vba sub...?

Comment: Both of my examples should be able to be used right in your SQL or your query designer. Hans does provide a function I didn't know about, DateValue, which might be even better.

Comment: INSERT INTO tblSearchEngine03 ( [Date] )
    SELECT tblSearchEngine02.Date
    FROM tblSearchEngine02
    GROUP BY tblSearchEngine02.Date;
    Format([tblSearchEngine02].[Date], "yyyy/mm/dd")

Comment: INSERT INTO tblSearchEngine03 ( [Date] ) SELECT CDate(Format([tblSearchEngine02].[Date], "yyyy/mm/dd"))  FROM tblSearchEngine02 GROUP BY Format([tblSearchEngine02].[Date], "yyyy/mm/dd")

Comment: Thanks Attila.. I think i almost have it..  Only that using that formating scheme in the document gives me an error message. I am tring Expr1:Format([date],"yyyy/mm/dd")

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49844/discussion-between-attila-and-marchese-il-chihuahua)

Answer (score 3):

Focus on the `SELECT` piece first.  You can use `DateValue()` for your `Date` field values.  Start with this as a new query in the Access query designer:

```sql
SELECT DateValue(se02.Date)
FROM tblSearchEngine02 AS se02
GROUP BY se02.Date
ORDER BY se02.Date
```

Or you could use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT DateValue(se02.Date)
FROM tblSearchEngine02 AS se02
ORDER BY se02.Date
```

After you have the `SELECT` working correctly, you can convert it to an `INSERT` query (the Access query designer calls it an "append" query).

And when you later build the same statement in your VBA code, include `Debug.Print st_sql` so that you can view the completed statement text in the Immediate window and make sure it is what you expected.  (You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to go to the Immediate window.)

Comment: Hans, what do you mean by DateValue()??  Does this mean i need to go to the properties and change something?

Comment: `DateValue()` is a function supported in Access SQL.  See the help topic in Access' built-in help system for details, or on the web: [DateValue Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datevalue-function-HA001228814.aspx)  It will give you the equivalent of `CDate(CInt([tblSearchEngine02].[Date]))`, which @attila suggested, but requires only one function to do it.

Comment: Sorry Hans, i hope i'm not wasting too much of your time..  I still don't understand how the DateValue plays a role in the Access Query Designer...

Comment: Now I don't understand.  Just try this: 1.) create a new query in the query designer 2.) switch to SQL View 3.) paste in the SQL text from one of the queries I suggested 4.) run the query.  Does it give you the results you want?

Comment: INSERT INTO tblSearchEngine03 ( [Date] )
GROUP BY tblSearchEngine02.Date;
SELECT DISTINCT DateValue(se02.Date)
FROM tblSearchEngine02 AS se02
ORDER BY se02.Date

Comment: That is not what I suggested.  Have you tried just the `SELECT` part (without any `INSERT`)?  Does that return the correct data?

Comment: Hans, i was working with Attila using your suggestion Select Distinct ... in the end, we couldnt get it to work..  We think there may be an issue with the European date format (here it is dd/mm/yyyy)..  Anywya, i solved the issue using a "workaround and 3 holding tables importing all the dates to one table, using the cDate function to import them to another table, and then running a Group query..

Answer (score 1):

Access stores its dates as floating point numbers where the integer part is the number of days since Jan 1, 1900 and the fractional part is the fraction of the day (time of day).  Access is quite happy to treat these dates as numbers without doing any conversions, so:

```
fix([tblSearchEngine02].[Date])
```

will trim the fractional part of the day and set the time back to midnight and allow you to group by day.

Comment: This is way better than the accepted answer because it also treats null values correctly.